# Disable http Trace method in RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I want to block/disable HTTP TRACE method on RabbitMq.

Basically, what I want is, when we hit RabbitMQ HTTP port like below, it should say, "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed" for TRACE method.
$curl -v -X TRACE http://server-name:15672

Comment: Does disabling management plugin fix this?

Comment: I have disabled the management plugin due to which HTTP port was disabled for all operations including rest APIs exposed by management plugin. Now, one of other component was using these APIs for monitoring purpose and they now want this to be enabled. We disabled this port at first place for security reasons. The team which got impacted by this has suggested using loopback interface. Can someone help me to know how loopback interface can solve my problem?